# Why does a conditional variable initialization need "var"?

Tags: javascript

If I remove "var", the browser(Chrome) complains : "someVar is not defined"

```
var someVar = someVar || {};
```

From what I know, it should complain only if I am not initializing the variable.

Comment: Without the `var`... you aren't initializing it. So it complains.

Comment: But if I say "someVar = 5;", I do not need a "var". Is it something to do with the conditional nature of initialization?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. Correct?

Comment: it is "Uncaught ReferenceError"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the function of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1048572)

Comment: These are all entirely wrong. Usually, constructs like this are used to prevent a variable from _not being_ defined _but_ take its "outer" value if it is already defined there. Whereas "outer" means somewhere else in the application where the script is used.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Without 'var' shouldn't it just initialize it as a global var? So what is the difference between this: a = {} (this works without problems) and a = a || {} (this throws an error) and var a = a || {} (this works, too). I am actually curious about this.

Comment: `a = 5` does *not* try to **read** `a`. `a = a || 5` tries to read `a`, so if it doesn't exist, an error is thrown.

Comment: @Bergi, I could not find a discussion on conditional value in the referenced thread.

Comment: *Setting* an uninitialised var will default to a global variable. *Getting* an uninitialised var will error.

Comment: @Paddy: It explains the difference between declared and undeclared variables. Accessing an undeclared variable will throw a reference error.

Comment: @FelixKling must be right. "someVar = 5 || {};" works fine.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I had missed that (pretty simple) deduction :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I know, it should complain only if I am not initializing the variable.

But you *are* trying to read an undeclared variable. Given

```
someVar = someVar || {};
```

it first evaluates `someVar || {}` and tries to get the value of `someVar` in the process. Since `someVar` doesn't exist (yet), you get a reference error.

Here is an example that does not throw an error:

```
someVar = true || someVar;
```

Because `||` does [shirt-circuiting evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the second operand is never evaluated and thus no error is thrown.

**Why does it work with `var` then?**

You might think that using the `var` keyword wouldn't make a difference since `someVar || {}` is still evaluated first. However, due to [**hoisting**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), the statement

```
var someVar = someVar || {};
```

is actually evaluated as

```
var someVar;
someVar = someVar || {};
```

So at the moment `someVar` is read, it is already declared.

Comment: So, I got confused with the hoisting thing, and this link discuses the concept in more mundane manner : http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html